# iOS in-app purchase sandbox mode testing logic

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

In my app there is a monthly auto-renewing subscription. We are doing server side validation based on `expires_date` from `latest_receipt_info`, then calculating and sending to app with `daysLeft` using this if `daysLeft > 0`, and then unlocking subscription features.

```
  if(_backendDaysLeft) {
        if(_backendDaysLeft.integerValue > 0) {
            NSLog(@"Subs :ACTIVE");
            status = SubscriptionStatusActive;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Subs :EXPIRED");
            status = SubscriptionStatusExpired;
        }
    }
```

But in sandbox mode always `daysLeft` will be `0` in our tests, and so is always `expired`. In sandbox mode 
If I change the condition to be `greater than zero (>0)` to `>=0` for sandbox mode testing and when I submit the app if I revert back to `>0`, will the Apple review team also use sandbox mode to unlock it?

How do I tackle this situation?

Comment: I would highly recommend not building such fragile logic into your app's purchase flow. Instead, use iOS's built-in markers to detect sandbox mode, and mock the successful response *only* for sandbox mode. I also suspect Apple will test in live mode, so you shouldn't worry about them ever testing in sandbox mode.

Comment: @brandonscript what is successfull response in sandboxmode ?

Comment: That's up to you? Mock a server response to always return the value you want to test with.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure but looks like your server-end calculation of days-left could be wrong. In Sandbox mode, a monthly Auto-Renewing subscription would expire in just 5 mins and a renew would trigger. This goes on for some 5 or so times, so in any case, your subscription gets canceled after some 30 mins or so.

If you are calculating days-left, seems to me, that this calculation could be flawed as 30 mins are too less than 24 hrs.

A better approach would be to return the exact date-time the subscription expires and use that in your app to enable/disable features.

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox subscriptions expire in ~5mins so "days left" is always 0.

Send back the `expires_date` and server timestamp to do the calculation on the client of time remaining.

Don't send back just an `expires_date` since the device time could be incorrect.

Comment: this is ok for when active internet what would be an approach if internet is not active.

Comment: Up to you. What we do in [our SDK](https://github.com/revenuecat/purchases-ios) is assume the subscription renewed if there's no internet connection and it's after the `expires_date`. We'd rather have a good offline experience for premium users then lock them out if there's no internet.